# Can SharePoint receive an email from itself?

Tags: 2010, email

SharePoint Foundation 2010, patched to Nov 2014 CU

I have two web applications in this farm.
A workflow from web application 1 sends an email.
One of the recipients of the email is a list in web application 2.
Emails are never delivered to the list in web application 2.

In ULS I see this error message for the particular email:
Errors occurred processing 1 message(s): Message ID:

The list in web application 2 receives the same email content without problem when sent directly from a user.

If I open the problem .eml in the drop folder I see the following header:
Received: from mysharepointserver.mydomain.local (1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) by
 myexchange.mydomain.local (1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
 8.3.342.0; Mon, 2 Feb 2015 13:09:44 -0700

There are other 'Received' headers in the .eml.

If I delete the header that references mysharepointserver.mydomain.local and save the .eml, SharePoint will process it accordingly.

I am led to believe that SharePoint will not process an email that it thinks was sent by itself, probably in an attempt to prevent a never ending chain of sent/received emails.

Can anyone confirm this?
Is there a workaround?

Thank You!

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPEmailEngine checks the following email headers using string.Equals: "X-AlertServerType", "STS" and "X-Mailer", "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010". If either are found it will not process the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint cannot send email to itself:

http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/03/sharepoint-cannot-send-mail-to-itself/

If you can strip out the X-Mailer value, then you'll be golden.